# Conventional name for coefficient in recurrence relation?

Tags: terminology, orthogonal-polynomials

Orthogonal polynomials are typically given in terms of their recurrence coefficients $\{\alpha_k\}_{k=1}^n$, $\{\beta_k\}_{k=1}^n$ via
$$
\begin{align*}
&p_0(x) = 1,\\
&p_1(x) = \text{something},\\
&p_k(x) = (x - \alpha_k) p_{k-1}(x) - \beta_k p_{k-2}(x).
\end{align*}
$$
In this case, the leading coefficient is always $1$.

Sometimes, it is desirable to scale the polynomials such that, e.g., $\|p_n\|=1$ with an appropriate norm. In this case, the recurrence takes the form
$$
p_k(x) = (c_k x - \alpha_k) p_{k-1}(x) - \beta_k p_{k-2}(x).
$$
Is there a conventional symbol for the coefficient here named $c_k$?

Comment: None of the usual references I have for orthogonal polynomials give a specific name; they all use "recurrence coefficients", with the modifier "orthonormal" or "monic" added as needed.

Comment: I meant the symbol, not the name. Will correct the question.

Comment: Ah. Usually, in the non-monic case, I see $$p_k(x) = (a_k x - b_k) p_{k-1}(x) - c_k p_{k-2}(x)$$ but there's no reason to be slavish in naming the letters as such. Just mention something like "the coefficients $a_k,b_k,c_k$ in the three-term recurrence (...)" and you'll be fine.

Comment: If you add any one reference and promote this to a reply, I'll be happy to mark this as the answer.

Comment: If you can wait a bit, I can do so tomorrow. I have no access to the usual references at the moment.

Comment: One source to cite might be Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials#Recurrence_relation.